How do I replace the hambuger off-canvas menu icon with text "donate"?
I'm using the Astroid framework. This is what I see when clicking the page source.
How to I change it to text instead of the burger - three lines - icon?
I'm assuming I need to add custom CSS code in the template settings. Can someone paste me the code please.
Thanks in advance!
div class="burger-menu-button active"
Customize the Offcanvas icons You now can customize that off-canvas icon using these simple overridable steps: Copy the files from this folder(JOOMLA_ROOT/libraries/astroid/framework/frontend/offcanvas) to this folder(JOOMLA_ROOT/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/frontend/offcanvas). Make the changes in the copied files. And it’s done, the changes made in those files with be reflected on your frontend just make sure to clear the cache as well.

You should edit your original post and add your comment to that original post to make it easier to understand. If you don't have the permission/access to do that let me know and I will do it for you.

Thanks. I have done so!

If you have found a solution to your problem you should un-delete the posts and provide your solution as an answer to help help people who may be looking in future.

So I created the JOOMLA_ROOT/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/frontend/offcanvas folder and pasted in there the two files from the JOOMLA_ROOT/libraries/astroid/framework/frontend/offcanvas folder:
close.php
trigger.php
In the trigger file I added the following code:
<div><span style="color:#a0b581; font-size:29px;"><i class="fa-brands fa-paypal"></i>

to use a fontawesome icon instead of the burger one.
